# Language for realtime, low-latency sound synthesis and fast processing?

Tags: performance, audio, documentation, cross-platform, sound-synthesis

I'm a IT student in the university, been programming in Visual Basic for a great time. Learnt Java here and C# by myself(really analog to Java). I am also a music producer, and I want to start working on a large project, just for myself, for fun and for expanding my knownledge.

I want to make a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) like Cubase, Reaper or Fruity Loops. Starting from small things like a Sound Sequencer. I already have some flow diagrams made.

I want to start coding it as soon as possible, but Java is an interpreted language as SuperCollider and Python, making it slow for processing. Visual Basic is not an option, I loved starting with it, but I don't like it anymore. I don't know if I should use C#, I, as a Linux lover, don't want to marry with Windows just because I need to use Visual Studio. I know there is Mono.

What is a good language for me? Could it be something:

1. Fast processing, non interpreted if its possible
2. Able to make my software crossplatform. Without the need of rewriting all the code, maybe just implementing some methonds for different systems.
3. With good documentation.

I know my question may be a little complicated, even can be seen as inmature. But I need help choosing a new language to learn.

Thanks for taking your time reading this. Every answer is appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much off-topic for SO, might be a better fit on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). On a side note, have you taken a look at [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didnt know about Programmers SE. I'm looking at Qt right now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Juce, which is written in C++.

I know that one very popular DAW is written with Juce. C++ has the added bonus that it is powerful and portable.

Answer (score 0):

[Extempore](https://github.com/digego/extempore) is fast and very cool. It's a pretty new project, but it's been used [for some very cool things.](http://vimeo.com/52964510)